# Disabled 'Shake mouse pointer to locate' setting in El Capitan but still get big cursor

Tags: macos, cursor, bettertouchtool

I have been able to disable the shake cursor to enlarge setting by going to `Settings > Accessibility > Display > Shake mouse pointer to locate` and disabling the option. The only issue is when I try and use the trackpad on Better Touch Tool Remote (iOS), the cursor is large all the time I am using the BTTR Trackpad!

Is there a way how I can fix this problem? I can only disable the big cursor when using the MBP trackpad not the BTTR one.

I am using El Capitan Public Beta build 15A262e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That just sounds like a bug to me. Really, like with all beta software, bugs are to be encountered in the OS X El Capitan Public Beta. In fact, that's the point of betas, let certain users find and report bugs so that Apple, or whatever developer, can fix them before the software reaches mainstream adoption. So, unfortunately, all you can really do is report that bug to Apple, using Feedback Assistant. If you **really** hate it, then you could either wait for the public release of El Capitan in a couple of weeks or downgrade to Yosemite. You could also try installing El Capitan again, but it just like a bug in the beta software to me.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for that. Lets hope it is a bug. Would Apple fix it though or would they say that it is a problem of the BTTR app?

Comment: @iProgram They might, so you may have to wait on the BTTR app to become compatible with El Capitan, too.

Comment: It is compatible though isn't it? The BTT El Capitan app is made for it (The app is beta) so the BTTR should be made for it?

Comment: @iProgram Good, at least it sounds like the devs are working on making it El Capitan ready. The bug is likely either in the El Capitan Beta or the app's beta, so report the problem to Apple and to the BTTR trackpad and hopefully the problem will be solved by the launch of the El Capitan release in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Ok, Will do. Also It it the trackpad with in BTTR (Better Touch Tool Remote) app. Not the BTTR trackpad. :)